# How to determine the strongest cipher suite for iOS application

Tags: ios8, ios9, app-transport-security

I need know, how to determine which is the strongest cipher suite for iOS application.Need a good Cipher suite which will provide maximum security for iOS 8 and iOS 9. When i went through Apple Docs, i found lot of cipher suites, some of them given below.

Example Cipher suites:
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,

Comment: Good information here : http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76993/now-that-it-is-2015-what-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-should-be-used-in-a-high-securit

Answer (score 0):

**first:** My main question is: do you want both iOS8 and iOS9 to support the same ciphersuite, or two different ones for example the best cipher of iOS8 and the best for iOS9?

As of Qualys SSL User Agent Capabilities page for [iOS 8](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Safari&version=8&platform=iOS%208.4) and [iOS 9](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Safari&version=9&platform=iOS%209), You should use:

- `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)` for iOS 8 and
- `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)` for iOS 9

Above Ciphersuites are only working with an ECDSA Key configuration.
If you only provide a RSA Key then you should use the following ciphers:

- `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)` for iOS 8 and
- `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)` for iOS 9 (Best performance)

I hope that answer can help you a bit.

Comment: I need cipher suite which will work on both IOS 8 and iOS 9. Need to send SSl certificate verification. Whether TLS 1.2 will on iOS 8?

Comment: Then the cipher `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384` would be the best to use i guess. Maybe you try it out! :-)